# How to find just Current time and just day in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i want to find just time not date from my computer current time and 
also find just "day" e.g., monday , tuesday etc from computer current day.
pls tell me as soon as possibe.

Comment: You can do it, really!

Comment: That isn't how this site works.  If you did any research, you would see this question is asked frequently.

Comment: [String Format for DateTime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime)

Comment: @ttoseeff check my answer, hope it helps

Comment: @BalajiM yes it so helpful gratitude

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the Day and Time in DateTime object (datestr). Check datestr object to get more information such as month, year, ShortTimeString.

```
DateTime datestr = DateTime.Now;
datestr.DayOfWeek; //it shows the day ex: monday,tuesday

datestr.ToLongTimeString(); //restult will be time ex: "10:18:19 PM"
```

Comment: Thanx bro. that's exactly what i wantt

Comment: can u tell me that how to add minutes in time

Comment: can u tell me that how to add minutes in time. For example, current time is  8:00 AM and i want to add 30 minutes in it. then the time will be 8:30 AM.

Comment: @ttoseeff  Use AddMinutes method datestr.AddMinutes(30).ToShortTimeString()

Comment: Please explain it why this is down voted?

Comment: Probably because that is what you get for answering *extremely* low quality questions. OP should try *something* on his own before asking for broad help.